# TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "int_const -1" to "uint256"

Tags: node.js, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

**I am trying to compile [WETH.sol found on Ethereum mainnet](https://etherscan.io/token/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2#code), which was compiled using a very old version (0.4.x). I changed the compiler version to ^0.8.0 and got the following error message.**

```
TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "int_const -1" to "uint256".
  --> contracts/WETH9.sol:78:64:
   |
78 |         if (src != msg.sender && allowance[src][msg.sender] != uint(-1)) {}
   |                                                                ^^^^^^^^


Error HH600: Compilation failed

**The code is as follows.**

if (src != msg.sender && allowance[src][msg.sender] != uint(-1)) {
            require(allowance[src][msg.sender] >= wad);
            allowance[src][msg.sender] -= wad;
        }
```

How can I correct this error?

Answer (score 3):

In versions of solidity prior to 0.8, the compiler does not protect you against underflows (or overflows).  So `uint(-1)` would underflow to give you the max `uint`.

The best practice to grab the max `uint` value is `type(uint).max`.

The code snippet is checking for an infinite approval. When an infinite approval has been given, it's common to assume the allowance doesn't need to be decreased.  This will save some gas from not needing to adjust storage.

So to upgrade the code snippet, it suffices to replace `uint(-1)` by `type(uint).max`.

Comment: Is it same as putting Zero(0) instead of uint(-1) ?

Comment: I updated my answer to explain the needed change.

Answer (score 2):

> An unsigned integer, declared with the uint keyword, is a value data
> type that must be non-negative; that is, its value is greater than or
> equal to zero.

So you cannot write this `uint(-1)`. value has to be a non-negative integer

`uint` and `uint256` are aliases.

Comment: 1) If I change -1 to zero(0) will it fix the problem. But will it affect the performance of the contract?
2) Link to the smart contract is below:
https://etherscan.io/token/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2#code

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that uint and uint256 are aliases, this has helped me:

```
uint256 mask = uint256(int256(-1));
```